# Is it possible to create users table after login in sequelize? and is it a correct way of handling mysqlDB?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

1.I already know that when server starts, automatically creates tables in model, however, I want to create tables of user(each users have their own table) when they Login, not when server starts. Is there any function of create new Table if not exist?(when user Login, not start of server.)

2.Also, I'm not sure whether it is a proper way of handling DB.  The reason I need to make tables per user is because I have to record the user's learning date for each chapter, But if there is 10000users, then I have to create 10000tables, and I'm not sure mysql can handle this much. So I tried other way, but I thinks this is the only way. perhaps use other DB like mongoDB.

Comment: Per user tables is definetely not how relational databases work, see here: https://towardsdatascience.com/designing-a-relational-database-and-creating-an-entity-relationship-diagram-89c1c19320b2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 3 tables:

1. `users` with userid, name, and other info you may want to save
2. `chapters` with chapterid, name, and other info you may want to save
3. `user_chapters` with userid, chapterid, learning_date, ...

This way, `users` table contains a list of all the users of your system. `Chapters` table holds chapters, and you can keep track of how users interact with chapters in the `user_chapters` table.

read more about entities and relations here: https://towardsdatascience.com/designing-a-relational-database-and-creating-an-entity-relationship-diagram-89c1c19320b2

Also, even 10 x 10000 records would be a piece of cake for MySQL. The bottleneck is usually indexes and how efficient are your queries. But that's 5 steps from where are you now.

EDIT:

So, you never ever create one table per user. That is not how relational databases work.

Whenever you register a new user, create a record in `users` table. Contents of the table may look like this:

```
userid    name
--------------
     1    Jonh
     2    Annie
     3    Bob
```

For each chapter you want to track, create a record in `chapters` table. It may look like this:

```
chapterid   name
------------------------
        1   Introduction
        2   First chapter
        3   Second chapter
        4   Another chapter
```

Now, when a user learns a chapter, create a record in `user_chapters` table. Like this:

```
userid   chapterid   learning_date
----------------------------------
     1           1      27-08-2021    // This shows that user #1 has completed chapter #1 on August 27, 2021
     1           2      28-08-2021 
     2           3      20-04-2020       // User #2 (Annie) completed chapter #3 (Second chapter) on April, 20
```

This structure of 3 tables allows keeping track of any number of users and chapters.

Now you want to know what chapters a user has completed. You can do that with the following SQL query:

```
  SELECT 
      A.name as user, C.name as chapter, learning_date 
  FROM 
      users A
  INNER JOIN
      user_chapters B on (A.userid = B.userid)
      chapters C on (B.chapterid = C.chapterid)
  WHERE 
      userid = 1
```

This will give you a list of chapters Jonh has completed.

```
 user   chapter         learning_date
 ------------------------------------
 Jonh   Introduction       27-08-2021
 Jonh   First chapter      28-08-2021
```

Comment: do you mean each user have each user_chapters table? for example, if three user exist, then create 3table? is it correct?

Comment: No, did you read the link I provided. Also, see the edit.